# How to change an object's property from function

Tags: javascript, node.js, recursion, pass-by-reference

I have the following function which resets an object with variable depth's deepest value to 0. I want the function to change the property of the object outside the function's scope;

```
    var object =
        { '1': {
                '10000': { '0': 6, '15': 3, '35': 5, '55': 3, '75': 85 },
            }
        } 

    function resetCounts(obj) {
        for (var el in obj) {
            if (obj.hasOwnProperty(el)) {
                if (typeof obj[el] == 'number') {
                    if (obj[el] > 0) {
                        console.log(obj)
                        console.log(obj[el]);
                        obj[el] = 0;
                        console.log('reset');
                        console.log(obj);
                        console.log(obj[el]);
                    }
                    return;
                }
                resetCounts(obj[el]);
            }
        }
    }

resetCounts(object);
```

Here is the result in the console:

```
{ '0': 6, '15': 3, '35': 5, '55': 3, '75': 85 }
6
reset
{ '0': 0, '15': 3, '35': 5, '55': 3, '75': 85 }
0
```

The expected result is for `object` to be:

```
        { '1': {
                '10000': { '0': 0, '15': 0, '35': 0, '55': 0, '75': 0 },
            }
        }
```

Any idea how this can be achieved? How can I pass the value to the parent object?

Comment: Why do you have a `return` statement? It's halting your loop after the first number is found. Simply remove it and use an `else` if you don't want a recursive call to happen.

Comment: OK. I'll try. I just edited my question to make it a bit more clear.

Comment: Thanks. That helped.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that "return;"  That returns from the function, thereby only leaving the first item changed.  Here's a fiddle:

https://jsfiddle.net/mckinleymedia/rbf26hcw/

```
function resetCounts(obj) {
  for (var el in obj) {
    if (obj.hasOwnProperty(el)) {
      if (typeof obj[el] == 'number') {
        if (obj[el] > 0) {
          obj[el] = 0;
        }
      }
      obj[el] = resetCounts(obj[el]);
    }
  }
  return obj;
};
var counts = { '0': 6, '15': 3, '35': 5, '55': 3, '75': 85 };
console.log(counts);
counts = resetCounts(counts);
console.log(counts);
```

So you know, using lodash, if you've just got counts in there AND you're not having to reset deep numbers, you could reset each tag with just this:

```
_.each(counts, function(v,k){ counts[k] = 0; });
```

Comment: Thanks for your help. Works perfectly.